# how do I pass date value from codebehind to markup page?

Tags: asp.net

I have this bit on codebehind:

```
txtDBirth.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("Mon dd yyyy")
```

We would like the date to appear in the format of Month Day Year as in Oct 07 2011

Then on the markup, I have this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDBirth" CssClass="TextBox" />
```

When we run this code, we would the value of this:

```
txtDBirth.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("Mon dd yyyy")
```

to appear inside

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDBirth" CssClass="TextBox" />
```

perhaps like:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDBirth" CssClass="TextBox"  value="Oct 07 2011/>
```

The idea is that the date value in the markup will change automatically to the current day's date.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you aware that the `<asp:TextBox/>` is translated into `<input type="text"/>` in the HTML? Maybe you don't want to change the `TextBox` at all?

Comment: Thank you John for the prompt response. What we are trying to do is compare that date with current date of Month day Year as indicated above. If the date on the markup page is equal to the current date, then show one message. If not, show another message. Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by simply doing sort of what you are already doing except that the format for your date is wrong. It should be something like:

```
txtDBirth.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy")
```

Will print:

> Oct 09 2011

You can't make the markup change automatically and you shouldn't need to, anyway. You are using a TextBox control and the `Text` Property is for setting the value inside the control.

**UPDATE (after reading comment to John Saunders):**

You could do:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtDBirth" />
```

On code behind:

You set `txtBirth.Text` from your data and then you compare:

```
If(txtDBirth.Text=DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy")) Then
   txtDBirth.Text = "Change to something different"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much Icarus for correcting that code. The way the former author of that code has it now is: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDBirth" CssClass="TextBox"  value="Aug 13 2011/>. Then on their codebehind, he used that date to determine whether certain criteria is met. Then a couple of months later, they manually change that date again to remove the criteria. We would like to handle it in such that no one needs to change that date manually anymore.

Comment: @Kenny I see. What you mean. But there must be a way to determine what the default value should be.